# Web Page not available on Gingerbread

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-2.3-gingerbread

If I run my code on Gingerbread Emulator it gives me:

Web Page not available and the source code of the page listed below.

If I run the app on ICS or JB (both phisical phone and emulator) it does work:

```
    webview = new WebView(InterfacciaPrincipale.this);

    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.loadData(Html.getHtml(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            new M("Caricamento", getApplicationContext());
            Log.v("ESSE3", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading()");
            System.out.println(url);
            try {
                Html.setHtml(Connessione.generaStringaHTML(Connessione.getUrl(url)));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(Html.getHtml());
            webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,Html.getHtml(), "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
            return true;

        }
    });
```

Yes, the INTERNET permission is there (it works on ICS and JB...).

Comment: Have you tried to access [www.google.com](http://www.google.com/) on the Gingerbread Emulator's Default Browser?

Comment: yes it displays google page. The emulator is connected to internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

```
webview.loadData(Html.getHtml(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

use

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,Html.getHtml(), "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
```

on Gingerbread. This fixed my problem.